# AutoCompleteTextView - when update adapter, dropdown auto close

Tags: android, kotlin, autocompletetextview

I use MaterialAutoCompleteTextView, when i add new item / items and call notifyDataSetChanged(), dropdown automatically closes

How to fix this

**VIDEO:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AYWW-_HcIpefrn0RcPMx2EsLLoyB2TtY/view?usp=sharing

**CODE:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var materialAutoComplete: MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
    private lateinit var adapter: CustomArrayAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        materialAutoComplete = findViewById(R.id.materialAutoComplete_main)

        setupMaterialAutoComplete()
    }

    private var number = 0

    private fun setupMaterialAutoComplete() {
        val items = mutableListOf("Shop", "Shop", "Shop", "Shop")
        adapter = CustomArrayAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.item_goods_material_auto_complete,
                items
        )
        materialAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter)

        object : CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                number += 1
                adapter.addAll(mutableListOf("$number", "${number + 1}"))
            }

        }.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really get the purpose of the CountDownTimer, please explain

Comment: This is just an imitation if you watch the video there you can see that after three seconds have passed, new elements will be added

Comment: I saw the video, but if you are updating the adapter, the AutoCompleteTextView can't be opened at the same time

Comment: It's not that just when the dropdown is open and new elements are added, it closes, I want to know how to fix it

Comment: Can you add where you are calling notifyDataSetChanged() ? It seems unrelated to the current code

Comment: It call in method addAll(), I checked when call notifyDataSetChanged, dropdown disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override this methods

```
class MaterialAutoCompleteTextViewWithoutAutoCloseDropdown : MaterialAutoCompleteTextView {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attributeSet)

    constructor(
        context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int,
    ) : super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr)

    override fun dismissDropDown() {
    }

    override fun onKeyPreIme(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && isPopupShowing) {
            if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.repeatCount == 0) {
                val state = keyDispatcherState
                state?.startTracking(event, this)
                return true
            } else if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                val state = keyDispatcherState
                state?.handleUpEvent(event)
                if (event.isTracking && !event.isCanceled) {
                    super.dismissDropDown()
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event)
    }

    override fun replaceText(text: CharSequence?) {
        clearComposingText()
        setText(text)
        val spannable = getText()
        Selection.setSelection(spannable, spannable.length)
        super.dismissDropDown()
    }
}
```